# Check Integer Value on Asmx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, soap, asmx

i have sample web method on my services,

```
 <WebMethod()> _
Public Function AddThis(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer

    Dim mySum As Integer

    If Not IsNumeric(x) Then
        Return 0
    End If
    mySum = x + y
    Return mySum

End Function
```

when i debug it, suddnely i made mistake about x or y value , and it give me an error :

System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert gf to System.Int32.
Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

i try to check the value :

```
If Not IsNumeric(x) Then
            Return 0
        End If
```

but keep getting the error, is it possible to check the value first before run the services?

Comment: Basically you are getting the error because you are passing a different type when you are supposed to pass an integer type. If you want you can change your parameter type to string and convert it to integer in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point you check "IsNumeric(x)", X will always be numeric.
You expect an Integer as parameters, so the error will occur the moment you call the function AddThis.

You will have to check X and Y before calling this function. Or if that is not possible, use something like this:

```
Public Function AddThis(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Integer

    Dim mySum As Integer

    If Not IsNumeric(x) Or Not IsNumeric(y) Then
        Return 0
    End If
    mySum = Integer.Parse(x) + Integer.Parse(y)
    Return mySum

End Function
```

Comment: okay, Got it, but i still curious, is it possible to keep the parameter as integer?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You will have to do the check 'IsNumeric' before you call "AddThis(x, y)"

Comment: oh okay, so someone who use my services should do that, thank you.